# Format string date time into desired format in python

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I have a variable which is of type **string** in timestamp format `Fri, 19 Mar 2021 06:15:55 +0000`

Used https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior to format but it throws `ValueError: time data 'Fri, 19 Mar 2021 06:15:55 +0000' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f'`

my code for changing format

```
pub_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(i.published, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S.%f').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pub_date=datetime.datetime.strptime(i.published, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

That last formatting code should not require a period and it should be a `%z` instead of `%f`

What is the difference between the codes?

`%f`
Used when microsecond are represented as a decimal number, zero-padded on the left.
For example: `000000, 000001, …, 999999`

`%z`
Used when the UTC offset is represented in the form `±HHMM[SS[.ffffff`]] (empty string if the object is naive).
For example: `+0000, -0400, +1030, +063415, -030712.345216`

## References:

`datetime` module in general: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Details about the format specification: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes

Comment: Thanks it worked, and well done for the appreciation